# ::memset crashes while initialising large array

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, c++17, memset

I am writing a C++ program that is aimed to work on a large volume of data. I was testing a particular function `HVE_KeyGen()` which takes in one large array along with other parameters. I have written a function `TestFunction()` to test the correctness of `HVE_KeyGen()`. Right now, this function is empty with only `return 0` statement. The program is compiling without any error. However, when I am executing TestFunction, the program is crashing (SIGSEGV error). While debugging I noticed that `::memset(v_vec,0xF0,262144);` is causing the crash. If I change this line to `::memset(v_vec,0x00,262144);`, the program does not crash. Although I can use a for loop to initialise the contents to 0xF0, I would still prefer using `memset`. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
int TestFunction(){

    uint8_t v_vec[262144];
    uint8_t hve_d0[16];
    uint8_t hve_d1[16];
    uint8_t hve_S[262144];
    uint8_t x_vec[262144];
    uint8_t hve_c_vec[4194304];

    ::memset(v_vec,0xF0,262144);//This causes crash

    ::memset(hve_d0,0x00,16);
    ::memset(hve_d1,0x00,16);
    ::memset(hve_S,0x00,262144);

    ::memset(x_vec,0x00,262144);
    ::memset(hve_c_vec,0x00,4194304);

    for(int i=0;i<262144;i++){
        v_vec[i] = 0xF0;
    }

    //msk is a global variable; hve_d0, hve_d1, and hve_S store output data
    HVE_KeyGen(hvemsk, v_vec, hve_d0, hve_d1, hve_S);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Just for curiosity, could you change 262144 to a smaller number? say 1024. and the same with 4194304. I want to see if it has something to do with the stack size instead of the actual memset. Does the problem still occur with smaller sizes?

Comment: Not sure if it's your problem, but you're using an awful lot of stack space.  Any chance you're overflowing?

Comment: You have declared ~5MB of local variables. How big is the stack on your machine?

Comment: Marginally related but using consts instead of magic numbers will make it easier to experiment with different values to see if it's stack space. For example, the value 262144 is repeated 5 times in that piece of code. Using a const means you only have to change it in one place. Also you can name the const to sometinhg that indicates its semantic intent within the current context. Doesn't fix your problem its just an observation.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your suggestions, it is a stack related issue indeed. It seems that hve_c_vec, which is really large, is the culprit (my stack space is not that large). If I remove this, it is working. This array is not used right now but will be required later. All of these, I declared as local variables just to check the functionality for now. In the main program, it is used differently. Thank you all once again for the suggestions.

Comment: @Arnab the stack is relatively small, don't put large amounts of data on it, allocate them dynamically instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I understand, I have modified the code to allocate dynamically. It is working perfectly. Thanks for your suggestion.